# Avoiding Call to OnCreate of background activity by pressing back of finish from Foreground Activity

Tags: android, oncreate, onresume, activity-lifecycle

I have two activity A and B.

I am calling B activity from A by pressing a Button. But when i press back button from B activity or call finish then it calls onCreate of activity A. I dont know why it is happening. Both the activities have data. Activity A is executing 3 Async Task threads simultaneously. I think due to less memory it is destroying background activity. But how to avoid it.

I want to that onCreate of A should not be called on press back or finishng from Activity B.

Comment: How are you creating Activity B? Do you use an intent with special flags? If you open Activity B in the same task as Activity A, Activity A [might be destroyed](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html). In any case, you should post some code.

Comment: can you put some code for calling b activity which u r used??

Comment: Code is Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16894686/disabling-re-execution-of-async-task-on-finishing-of-foreground-activity

Comment: @verybadalloc see question on above link

Comment: @Stackoverflow  see code on above link

Answer (score 0):

If Activity A was closed down due to memory and `onCreate` is being called again when you go back to it, then `savedInstanceState` in `onCreate` will not be null. You can simple check for `savedInstanceState == null` and execute accordingly.

Example:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // Do stuff
    }     
}
```

Comment: did you change the `launchMode` in the `manifest.xml` of your activity?

Comment: That's what I'm asking. What is the value of this attribute? Is it there?

Comment: No its not there. But what to put there?

Comment: Nothing, I was just checking. The code you posted above doesn't contain SetupViews() where I assume you set up the button press to call Activity B. Without more information it's hard to say what's going on.